# Subclipse: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, svn, subclipse

I have got an error while I'm trying to commit/update project in Eclipse (in terminal no problems).

Window details:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/<my_patch>'
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/<my_path>'
```

Console:

```
svn: E175002: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/<my_path>'
    svn: E175002: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/<my_path>'
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    Could not generate DH keypair
    Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
```

I'm using SvnKit 1.8 and this problem came suddenly after long time of using this connector.
I tried to delete eclipse's files/download and prepare new enviroment, download newest java, update system(MAC). Nothing worked.. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You should send email to support@svnkit.com but it looks like some JVM/JRE issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the command line SVN client works you can use the JavaHL connector. It uses the same library as the command line client.

If you are dependend on SvnKit you can try to install:

- For Java 6: [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html).
- For Java 8: [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).

Comment: Works like charm for me with Java8. I had to download the appropriate policy file, so I updated your answer with the link for JDK8 too.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

First, I selected SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.8.12.10533, but failed.
Then I selected JavaHL (JNI) 1.9.3 (r1718519) and succeeded.