# Jenkins checkout ERROR: svn: E175002: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: ssl, svn, jenkins

Jenkins unable to check out the code during the build process. It shows the following error message 
**ERROR: Failed to check out
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair**

But i can manually checkout the code in build server (Slave servers). Its failing through Jenkins build process. 
I have not used my Jenkins build server for some time and I didn't do any changes/upgrade in the build server but strangely getting the above error.

Jenkins version: **1.609.3** , Java version - **1.6.0_91**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Bala.

Comment: Have you changed your credentials recently?

Comment: No, I didn't change the crentials recently

Comment: Please refer similar issues :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713813/subclipse-could-not-generate-dh-keypair.

Comment: You should upgrade Java to 1.8 or newer to solve the problem.